# Запятые в переводе фразы из Корана

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, с запятыми. Правильно ли я расставила их? Нужна запятая после слова "Аллаху"?

**Воистину, все мы принадлежим Аллаху, и, поистине, все мы возвращаемся к Нему.**

Comment: В религиозных текстах, как я понимаю, воистину не является вводным, это утверждение истины, а не предположение. Воистину используется в молитвах и прочих посланиях. В разговорной же речи используется оборот поистине, его тоже не обособляют, но вместе они в одном предложении рядом смотрятся странно. Кроме того обе части до и после И выглядят как почти полная тавтология.

Правильно ли я расставила их - правильно ли я их расставила(слова немного перепутаны, так тоже можно, но тут перестановка слов звучит неуместно.)

Comment: Нужна ли запятая после "Аллаху"? - слово "слово" звучит лишним, особенно рядом с именем Бога.

Comment: Перевод от клиента, хочет такую гравировку. У клиента стояли запятые везде, кроме той, о которой я спросил. Рядом будет текст непосредственно вязью на арабском. Просто хотят ещё и личный перевод. Я думаю перевод в принципе не уместен с арабского. Но вот захотели... Проблема в том, чтобы было грамотно написано по-русски и не пришлось догравировывать, когда кто-то им укажет на ошибку. А так я тут пишу, потом показываю в качестве доказательства, и они мне начинают верить)

Comment: Я посмотрел переводы Корана, скорее всего это не совсем верно переданный перевод Османова. "Воистину, мы принадлежим Аллаху, и, поистине, к Нему мы и вернемся".

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться у заказчика, этот ли перевод он имеет ввиду или у него другой(на сайте https://falaq.ru/ есть несколько переводов, но ни один не повторяет данную фразу). Если он хочет, чтобы ему сделали именно его фразу, то это его право, тогда нет смысла спорить из-за орфографии и версий перевода. Но запятые именно так и стоят и воистину - поистине присутствуют...

Comment: «Поистине, мы принадлежим Аллаху (и Он поступает с нами, как пожелает), и поистине, мы (только) к Нему возвращаемся (после того, как умрём и мы надеемся получить от Него награду за наше терпение)!» Либо вот этот перевод "Аль-мунтахаб фи тафсир аль-Куран Аль-карим" (Аль-Азхар).

Comment: Но тут другие запятые). Место - сура 2. 156